# Store data in built-in Flash of PIC at runtime using C code

Tags: microcontroller, c, programming, flash

I am designing PIC16F877a based project that counts the number of people in a room and turn ON the relays in accordance with that number like if 5 persons in a room then One relay would be ON. I want user of the device to set the number according to their need therefore I want to store some integers variables (value defined by user) in a Flash memory on uC at runtime using C code. I have searched on Google but did not find any suitable answer.

Comment: Your PIC has 256 bytes of EEPROM; you can use that to store your variables. Depending on the compiler, it may have some built-in function to read/write the EEPROM memory.

Comment: @m.Alin I am using HI-TECH C compiler. What built in functions are available for it.

Comment: unsigned char eeprom_read (unsigned int address);   void eeprom_write (unsigned int address, unsigned char value);   |   You should include the htc.h header file

Comment: I know "Use Google" answers are frowned upon, but re: `I am using HI-TECH C compiler. What built in functions are available for it.` Seriously, just google "Hi-tech c pic eeprom" and the easily first 10 results are exactly what you want.

Comment: @Connor : that search works because you already know one search term that wasn't in the original question!

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I was responding to his comment, not the original answer. The original question is fine. Asking about the functions the compiler you are using has available is a bit silly, particularly when you asking such in response to a comment that does provide the relevant search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the processor you are using this should be as simple as eeprom_write(unsigned int address,unsigned char data), in which you can find the address of the eeprom/flash in the datasheets. Some processors don't seem to support this command though. If you look in the header file of the uC as well as the compiler header (eg. pic18.h) you can see whether certain commands have been commented out due to no definition being previously defined. If no definition, you will have to do it bit-wise and make sure that you do not cross with any vital program memory during run time.

Comment: Just a note that not all PICs have EEPROM.  It appears that Microchip is no longer including EEPROM on a lot of the newer chips.  The PIC32's generally do not have EEPROM.